# D.C. Madman with cat cannon?

Tags: character-identification

I recently heard Trevor Noah of the Daily Show say:

> Not to be confused with the D.C. Madman, the eccentric 19th century scientist known for attacking the White House with a cat-cannon

Who exactly is he referring to?

Comment: Any particular reason to think they mean a DC Comics character and not a mad man from Washington, DC?

Comment: Just for those of us not familiar with The Daily Show, _who_ is not to be confused with said madman?

Comment: Also, especially if it turned out it was a made up story and not real history, is a question about a 19th century cat cannon really off topic? (Or course, the OP shouldn't have confused DC with D.C., but that's beside the point.)

Comment: @MrLister He just said something about the "D.C. Madam" immediately before. I thought the context is a bit dark (the D.C. Madam was a real person), and the only association is a play on words, so I didn't post it. 
 AnthonyGrist, Not really, except the claim sounded ludicrous, so I thought it might be a comical character...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It was a joke.
2. The joke involves a fictional attack on the White House.
3. The White House is in Washington, D.C.
4. The fictional attacker is known as the D.C. Madman because he's insane and he is famous because of his cat-cannon-and-Presidential-mansion-related actions in Washington, D.C.
5. This isn't a real story, or a real character, except insofar as Trevor Noah told a story about said character, in the form of the aforementioned joke.

Comment: I understood it's a joke, but usually Mr. Noah doesn't make a baseless joke - it usually alludes to something. So you're saying this story does not allude to any real or fictional character in literature or real life? It seems rather bizarre that he would make something up completely out of the blue.

Comment: @user4624937 - the reference to real events was the part you didn't mention - whatever we're not supposed to confuse with the D.C. Madman.  It isn't bizarre at all for a comedian to make something up.  That's often how comedy works.